# enumitem and \@listdepth

Tags: lists, enumitem

The labels in itemize-like lists created with `enumitem` don't seem to
obey `\@listdepth`. Consider the following. We define two types of lists

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{foolist}{itemize}{2}
\newlist{barlist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[foolist,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[foolist,2]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[barlist,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[barlist,2]{label=\textendash}
```

With either type of list we should get a bullet when the list is not nested
and a dash when it is.  However, in practice, this only occurs if the parent list is the same kind as the nested one.

```
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{foolist}
  \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \begin{foolist}
      \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \end{foolist}
\end{foolist}

\begin{foolist}
  \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \begin{barlist}
      \item Bar \the\@listdepth
    \end{barlist}
\end{foolist}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The code above produces

```
* Foo 1
  - Foo 2

* Foo 2
  * Bar 2
```

Even though `\@listdepth` in the last `barlist` is set two 2, the label is a bullet.

How can I make the labels to depend solely on the value of `\@listdepth`
regardless of the kind of list?

Comment: The depth is defined in a new counter of every initialised environment with `enitdp@<env-name>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\@listdepth` as part of the `label` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

\newlist{foolist}{itemize}{2}
\newlist{barlist}{itemize}{2}
\makeatletter
\setlist[foolist]{label={\ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne\textbullet\else\textendash\fi}}
\setlist[barlist]{label={\ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne\textbullet\else\textendash\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{foolist}
  \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \begin{foolist}
      \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \end{foolist}
\end{foolist}

\begin{foolist}
  \item Foo \the\@listdepth
    \begin{barlist}
      \item Bar \the\@listdepth
    \end{barlist}
\end{foolist}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```